# Cannot Access Store Data after Initialization

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css, nuxt3, pinia

I am developing a Nuxt 3 SPA that has a Single API call that I make in the `onMounted()` hook in my `app.vue`. I use Pinia and I have defined a function in my Pinia store and I call that function to execute my `GET` API Call. I have verified using the Network Monitor in the Broswer Inspect Menu that the API has been called and the data has been retrieved and initialized in the Store. But when I try to access the same store data in my `pages/index.vue`, I am not able to access the data.

`// index.js script setup tag`

```
<script setup>
  const store = useGlobalStore();
  console.log(store.content.seo); // Returns Undefined.
</script>
```

In the above code snippet, i want to dynamically assign the values i get in the `store.content.seo` in the `useSeoMeta()` hook provided by Nuxt 3.

The same thing happens with any other component as well:

`header component`

```
<template>
  <header
    class="relative bg-black w-screen h-screen flex flex-col items-center justify-start py-32"
  >
    <NuxtImg
      :src="content.avatar ? content.avatar : '/img/header.webp'"
      class="absolute top-0 left-0 w-full h-full object-cover opacity-50"
    />
    <div class="w-full h-full p-10 flex flex-col items-center justify-between">
      <div class="flex z-10 flex-col items-center justify-center space-y-6">
        <h1 class="w-full text-center text-white font-semibold text-2xl">
          {{ content.title }}
        </h1>
        <a
          href="#contact"

                         // dynamically assign button color but not working
          :class="`shine bg-[${content.theme.primary}] z-10 text-white text-xl px-10 py-4 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center`"
         
 >Discover More</a
        >
      </div>
      <button
        @click="toggleModal(true)"
        class="w-28 h-28 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center p-3 backdrop-blur-sm bg-white/30 animate-shadow-ping"
      >
        <Icon
          name="material-symbols:play-arrow"
          color="#003989"
          class="w-full h-full"
        />
      </button>
    </div>
  </header>
</template>

<script setup>
  const { content, toggleModal } = useGlobalStore();
</script>
```

in the above `header` component, I want to dynamically assign the theme color I get from my API but this doesn't work. Please Help.